# What is the correct way to change the LocationStrategy from HashLocationStrategy to PathLocationStrategy in a jhipster/angular app?

Tags: angular, jhipster

In a jhipster/angular gateway application, I am trying to change the LocationStrategy from HashLocationStrategy to PathLocationStrategy. The reason for this change is that I try to authenticate users using Linkedin and in the Linkedin app configuration I am required that the callback URL cannot contain hash #

I have read about it in different sources and the option that has approached me the most consisted of the following:

1. In `src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts` I assign to `useHash` the value `false` in the object of the second argument of `RouterModule.forRoot()` function
2. In `src/main/webapp/index.html` in  of the index.html I add `<base href='/'>` as recommended in [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href-1)

With the above I manage to eliminate the hash of the main page, I also manage to authenticate, but when trying to navigate within the app it fails, the following error can be read in the browser console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.
provideForRootGuard@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js:5608:15
_callFactory@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21635:20
_createProviderInstance@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21591:26
initNgModule@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21521:32
NgModuleRef_@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22248:21
createNgModuleRef@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22237:12
NgModuleFactory_.prototype.create@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:24772:25
RouterConfigLoader.prototype.load/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js:3678:34
MapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js:40:35
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:63:18
MergeMapSubscriber.prototype.notifyNext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:94:26
InnerSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:19:21
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:63:18
subscribeToPromise/</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.js:10:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:26
onInvoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:17652:33
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:389:52
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:149:43
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:888:34
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422:31
onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:17643:33
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:60
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:194:47
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:600:35
promise callback*scheduleMicroTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:583:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:412:38
onScheduleTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:300:29
ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:403:51
Zone.prototype.scheduleTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:237:43
Zone.prototype.scheduleMicroTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:257:25
scheduleResolveOrReject@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:878:14
resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:824:44
makeResolver/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:740:31
webpackJsonpCallback@https://localhost:9060/app/main.bundle.js:26:29
@https://localhost:9060/app/42.chunk.js:1:57
```

`src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts` look similar to this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            [
                {
                    path: 'admin',
                    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
                },
                {
                    path: 'lorem',
                    loadChildren: './lorem/lorem.module#LoremModule'
                },
                {
                    path: 'ipsum',
                    loadChildren: './ipsum/ipsum.module#IpsumModule'
                }
            ],
            { useHash: false, enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
        )
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `forRoot()` function was used more than once, and one of them within a feature module, changing `forRoot()` in this feature module to `forChild()` solved the problem

From [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#forroot-and-forchild)

> Use forRoot() only once in the application, inside the
> AppRoutingModule